# send GET request via php

Tags: php, curl, get, request

I need to send a GET request to remote server with xml parameters.

example:

```
https://url.com/test.jsp?<xml></xml>
```

how to do it?

I tried to do with cURL, but the certificate error. Also tried to disable checking but to no avail.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

any idea? is it possible to do this using the file_get_contents() ?

Comment: Why don't use $_POST?

Comment: no, only get request

Comment: Send all parameter as normal get request ? Any problem occur in that?

Comment: here the problem is not in the parameter. I say again, the problem Certificates.

Answer (score 0):

cURL uses `GET` by default, and normally you'd use GET when, well, getting something from the server. As opposed to `POST` used to post data to a sever.

You can pass in your parameters as you would normally when using GET.

```
https://url.com/test.jsp?someXmlData=data&someOtherXmlData=someOtherData
```

You could used `file_gets_content` as long as you know the url from which you want to get the data.

Comment: Ah, well that's a whole other story then. cURL used to verify, by default, SSL certificates. It no longer does so. Head over to [this link](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html) and have a read.

Comment: You want to say that without the certificate, it will not work?

Comment: Well yes, that's how Secure Sockets Layer works. It's...secure.

Comment: I think that everything is still possible to do it without a certificate, i will look and dig deeper.